# prevent divs from overlapping

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm having troubles with my divs overlapping on a html page I'm making. Namely the one with the wrapper is overlapping the header with the menu (`openbt`) button in it.

I've tried reordering the divs in the body section but that doesn't seem to help. I've also tried to use `clear: both` in for `.main` and `.wrapper` neither changed anything.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "260px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#EFEFEF, #505050);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.sidenav {
  /*Main sidnav*/
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #000A0F;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: .5s;
  padding-top: 46px;
}

.sidenav a {
  /*sidenav buttons*/
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  /*sidnav button hover*/
  color: #818181;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: fixed;
}

.active {
  background-color: #000A0F;
  color: white;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  color: #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0px;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 6px 0px 6px 0px;
}

.header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 46px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #004063;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 1px 0px 1px;
  border-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.openbt {
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #004063;
  padding: 3px 0px 2px 20px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
  border-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.openbt:hover {
  /*sidnav button hover*/
  color: #818181;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.form {
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 220px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 7px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.7);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.button {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.7);
  color: #000000;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <div class="header">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <a href="Index.html">Home</a>
</div>

<div class="header">
  <div class="openbt" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Menu</div>
</div>

<div class="main">

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="form">
      <h2>Edit Account</h2>
      <form action="edit_account.php" method="post">
        E-Mail Address:<br />
        <input type="text" name="email" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Update Account" />
      </form>
      <br/><br/>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I can never make my code look nice on here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `.header` is `position:absolute` and `.main` is `position:fixed`, they are both removed from the normal [document flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning#Document_flow) and overlap each other.

One solution is to let them both be `position:static` (the default) or set them to `position:relative` so that they flow with the document.

```
.main {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.header {
  height: 46px;
  background-color: #004063;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 1px 0px 1px;
  border-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "260px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#EFEFEF, #505050);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.sidenav {
  /*Main sidnav*/
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #000A0F;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: .5s;
  padding-top: 46px;
}

.sidenav a {
  /*sidenav buttons*/
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  /*sidnav button hover*/
  color: #818181;
}

.main {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #000A0F;
  color: white;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  color: #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0px;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 6px 0px 6px 0px;
}

.header {
  height: 46px;
  background-color: #004063;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 1px 0px 1px;
  border-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.openbt {
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #004063;
  padding: 3px 0px 2px 20px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
  border-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.openbt:hover {
  /*sidnav button hover*/
  color: #818181;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.form {
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 220px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 7px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.7);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.button {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.7);
  color: #000000;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <div class="header">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <a href="Index.html">Home</a>
</div>

<div class="header">
  <div class="openbt" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Menu</div>
</div>

<div class="main">

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="form">
      <h2>Edit Account</h2>
      <form action="edit_account.php" method="post">
        E-Mail Address:<br />
        <input type="text" name="email" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Update Account" />
      </form>
      <br/><br/>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

If you must have them positioned as you do, you can push `.main` down by the height of `.header`:

```
.main {
  top: 46px;
  ...
}
```

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "260px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#EFEFEF, #505050);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.sidenav {
  /*Main sidnav*/
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #000A0F;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: .5s;
  padding-top: 46px;
}

.sidenav a {
  /*sidenav buttons*/
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  /*sidnav button hover*/
  color: #818181;
}

.main {
  top: 46px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: fixed;
}

.active {
  background-color: #000A0F;
  color: white;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  color: #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0px;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 6px 0px 6px 0px;
}

.header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 46px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #004063;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 1px 0px 1px;
  border-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.openbt {
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #004063;
  padding: 3px 0px 2px 20px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
  border-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.openbt:hover {
  /*sidnav button hover*/
  color: #818181;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.form {
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 220px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 7px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.7);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.button {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.7);
  color: #000000;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <div class="header">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <a href="Index.html">Home</a>
</div>

<div class="header">
  <div class="openbt" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Menu</div>
</div>

<div class="main">

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="form">
      <h2>Edit Account</h2>
      <form action="edit_account.php" method="post">
        E-Mail Address:<br />
        <input type="text" name="email" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Update Account" />
      </form>
      <br/><br/>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

For reference, see [position @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Values)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your .form div

```
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Your header is positioned absolutely, so your other content will flow as if it's not there. You probably should use position:relative for your header and display:block instead of inline block.

Once you do that, content will flow underneath. Then you'll need to use a bit of a margin so the elements aren't touching.

In this case, since your .form looks like a modal, it's good to position it fixed and in the middle of the view. code above does this.